# libGDX manager.update() blocking animations

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, gif

I successfully implemented a gifdecoder in my project and wrote a gifloader for it to use it with the assetmanager. I am able to load the gif in the assetmanager and I am also able to draw it. But everytime I try to load gifs in my assetmanager with manager.update() I can not draw animations anymore, only non animated textures.

Here is my code I hope somebody has an idea

```
public class Load implements Screen {

private SpriteBatch batch;
private Animation<TextureRegion> loadingAnimation;
private TextureAtlas atlasLoading = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("atlas/loadingAnimation.atlas"));
float stateTime;
MainExecute lr;

public FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
public AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();
private final Animation animation = GifDecoder.loadGIFAnimation(Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL, Gdx.files.internal("data/loading.gif").read());
public Load(MainExecute lr){
    this.lr = lr;
}
public Texture Bg1;

@Override
public void show() {
    Bg1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bggamescreen.png"));
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    manager.setLoader(GIF.class,new Gifloader(resolver));
    manager.load("data/BackgroundAnim.gif",GIF.class);
    stateTime = 0f;
}





@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    if (manager.update())
    {


        lr.setScreen(new MainMenu(lr)); 
    }

    stateTime += delta;
  //  loadingAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.5f, atlasLoading.findRegions("loading"),Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
    TextureRegion currentFrame = (TextureRegion) animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);


    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(Bg1,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.draw(currentFrame, 0, 0, 200, 200);
    batch.end();







}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Strange code, you are drawing animation before it finish loading. You need to waiting to load your animation, try smth like this.

```
    if (manager.update())
    {
        loadingAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.5f, atlasLoading.findRegions("loading"),Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
        TextureRegion currentFrame = (TextureRegion) animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);

        lr.setScreen(new MainMenu(lr)); 
    }
```